# ASP.NET bundles looking for files in arbitrary locations

Tags: asp.net

I was adding all my css/js to my layout manually, as in, right on the page. I decided I may as well use the bundles to simply things (apparently not).

The first bundle causing an issue:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css",
                  "~/Content/daterangepicker-bs3.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.common.min.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.mobile.all.min.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.default.min.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Which causes nice errors like:

```
http://localhost:58703/Content/images/kendoui.ttf?v=1.1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:58703/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I should note that the most ridiculous part about these errors is that if I click the URL's that it's saying it can't find the file in, the files are **right there**, exactly where it says it can't find them in.

The next bundle causing an issue:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mapcrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2015.2.624/jszip.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.all.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js",
                "~/Content/jscolor.js",
                "~/Scripts/graphstuff.min.js"));
```

Which causes silly behaviour like:

```
http://localhost:58703/jscolor/arrow.gif  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:58703/jscolor/hs.png  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:58703/jscolor/cross.gif  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried some of the fixes I've found while searching, most of them were citing issues with version 1.1.1 I believe, however, that was several years ago. Unless M$ has yet to actually make this bundling stuff work.

Its beginning to appear as if it is fabricating random URLs as it goes along. It is now looking for 'kendoui.woff' in

```
'\Content\images\kendoui.woff'
```

When the correct location is

```
\Content\kendo\2015.2.624\images\kendoui.woff
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to bundles. It sounds like your bundles are loading OK but then content they reference (ttf, woff, gif, png) can't be found. May want to check your mime types are configured correctly eg http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Comment: Ya unfortunately that URL falls under the 'things I've already tried' category.

Answer (score 12):

I'm a bit late but was getting the same 404 error for font-awesome `/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0` and fixed it by adding these lines to web.config file under `<system.webServer>`:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: hi , can you explain how did you come up with that solution? thank !

Answer (score 3):

MS does have a class to handle the issue, to make it work simply use the following code:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/*.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Notice CssRewriteUrlTransform, it will change your relative links inside css to the correct ones before caching the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Look there for Telerik clarification:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#css-bundling

The bundling has to be done in this way:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/...VERSION.../css").Include(
"~/Content/kendo/...VERSION.../kendo.common.min.css",
"~/Content/kendo/...VERSION.../kendo.default.min.css"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing is not due to any problem with the bundle itself, rather the resources in the files you are bundling are referencing other files with a relative path.  Because your bundle has a different path structure than the physical files, the relative paths don't properly reference the files.

To correct this, you can either manipulate the bundle path structure so that the relative paths are still correct, or you can change the relative paths (../images/whatever.gif) to absolute paths (/images/whatever.gif or http://www.someothersite.com/whatever.gif).

You might also have an issue with missing MIME types configured in IIS for the .woff file which would result in a 404 even if the file was present.

Comment: Thanks, I've opted to simply not use bundles though. If you have to force VS to realize the correct paths to things then it simply isn't worth the hassle until they figure that out themselves.

Comment: It has nothing to do with visual studio, or Microsoft, or ASP.NET,  If you were to bundle it using any other tool, and placed the bundle in a different path, using only static files, the same problem would occur.

Comment: If I can link to the files on the page in the identical manner in which I pass the file paths to the bundles, then Microsoft is not doing the pathing correctly. You should not have to edit static JS libraries hard coded paths to make a 'bundle' work.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't defined the path, you defined the path of the bundle - StyleBundle("~/Content/css").   Take your Kendo CSS for example, natively it uses multiple paths like /kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.common.min.css, however you've flattened this down to a single path (/content).  Hence why your relative paths are failing to load resources

Comment: That's exactly it. It can find the path '/kendo/2015.2.624/kendo.common.min.css' no problem, even if the bundle is specified as StyleBundle("~/Content/css")  - the issue is any relative paths INSIDE kendo.common.min.css will resolve incorrectly if they are loaded in the bundle.

Comment: "Microsoft is not doing the pathing correctly" is not correct. @Steven has explained perfectly the mistake you're making. When you bundle CSS/JS, any paths are then relative to your bundle and not the source files. So where before your content was relative to `/kendo/2015.2.624/` it is now relative to `/Content/css` which is why you're getting 404s.

Comment: If that is the intended behaviour of their bundles then I don't really see how that's any better than if they're just doing it wrong anyway.